# How is executing a startup script different to writing the commands manually?

Tags: script, boot, redhat-enterprise-linux

This is my Node.JS webserver startup script for RedHat EL 6.

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig:   345 01 01
# description: DeepFlow startup script

case $1 in
        start)
            echo "Starting DeepFlow"
            cd /home/admin/Desktop/DeepFlow/server
            ./bin/node js/server.js
            ;;
        stop)
            echo "Stopping DeepFlow"
            killall node
            ;;
esac
```

For some reason, when I manually type

```
            cd /home/admin/Desktop/DeepFlow/server
            ./bin/node js/server.js
```

everything works fine, but when I do `service DeepFlow start` I get a Node.JS error:

```
Starting DeepFlow

events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

What is the difference between manually typing the script lines in a terminal, and running the script with `service`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using full pathnames.

```
NODE_BIN="/home/admin/Desktop/DeepFlow/server/bin/node"
SERVER_JS="/home/admin/Desktop/DeepFlow/server/js/server.js"
echo "Starting DeepFlow"
$NODE_BIN $SERVER_JS
;;
```

Also it would be good to check which user is starting the server. If it's run on startup, the owner will be 'root'.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Do you have some library path in your env-variables? Maybe using export NODE_PATH="/home/admin/Desktop/DeepFlow/server/" would help.